# Как заменить четные элементы матрицы единицей?

Tags: pascal

> Целочисленная матрица n-порядка создается из случайных чисел. Заменить все четные элементы матрицы единицей.

Вот начало программы:

```
Program grovewp;

Uses crt;

Var    A:   Array[1..50,1..50] Of integer;
    ms:   array[1..25] Of integer;
    i,j,n,m,max:   integer;
Begin

    writeln('Вв кількість рядків    матриціA');
    readln(n);
    writeln('Вв. кількість стовпців    матриці A');
    readln(m);
    writeln('Матриця A має вид');

    For i:=1 To n Do
        For j:=1 To m Do
            A[i,j] := random(70)-20;
    For i:=1 To n Do
        Begin
            For j:=1 To m Do
                write(A[i,j],' ');
            writeln;
        End;
End
```

Comment: @grovewp, Отредактируйте свой код. Добавьте пояснение, в чем вы видитет проблему.

Comment: Изменил....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
i,j,n :integer;
A : array[1..50,1..50];
begin
 n = 50;
 randomize();
 for i:=1 to n do
 begin
 writeln;
   for j:=1 to n do
   begin 
     a[i,j]:=random(100)-50;
     write (a[i,j],' '); 
   end;
 end;

 for i:=1 to n do
 begin
 writeln;
   for j:=1 to n do
   begin 
     if (a[i,j] mod 2 = 0) then
       a[i,j]:=1;
     write (a[i,j],' '); 
   end;
 end;

end.
```